# How to add a custom task pane to Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, add-in, customtaskpane

I am creating an add-in for Visual Studio 2012. I want to create a custom task pane that I could fill with files and folders that could be selected and opened by a developer. I have found a lot of documentation on how to create add-ins with task panes for MS Office, but I can't find anything about how to add a task pane to Visual Studio with an add-in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the professional version of 2012 you can use the following link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942846(v=vs.110).aspx

Essentially you will need to add a User Control (this becomes your custom task pane)

If you are using express edition of Visual Studio it would be ideal to download and use NetOffice - http://netoffice.codeplex.com/

The following is an example of the code I have used in my project. I have added a user control called UserControl1. This is using the Ultimate version however it is the same for at least the professional version.

```
Private myUserControl1 As UserControl1
Private myCustomTaskPane As Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

    myUserControl1 = New UserControl1
    myCustomTaskPane = Me.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl1, "Picture Table Editor Pane")

    With myCustomTaskPane
        .DockPosition = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionFloating
        .Width = 300
        .Height = 400
        .DockPosition = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionLeft
        .Width = 300
    End With

End Sub
```